# IE8 first page takes ages to load, but then all others load fine

Tags: windows-vista, internet-explorer-8

One of my clients recently got a new laptop - I set it up and everything was working well.

Since then he has started to have a issue with Internet Explorer 8; when it first starts up, it takes a minute to load the first page, and then all others open fine.

During this minute he can open and close tabs, but all pages take a long time to load until the first one has completed loading.

Does anyone have any idea what is causing this, and any possible solutions?

Comment: Have any add-ins or activex been installed?

Comment: I will double check, but i doubt it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is usually caused by IE's Tools -> Options -> Connections -> LAN Settings -> "Automatically detect settings" being checked.  For some reason, figuring out what proxy to use on the network takes *forever*.  Clear the checkbox, and if you have a proxy, type it in below.  Otherwise leave the rest of the box unchecked and blank as well.  That should get your first page coming up very fast.

Comment: I think this will fix the problem, just waiting for client to get out of a meeting to test.

Comment: this could definitely be the reason. However I don't think this is enabled by default in IE?

Comment: just checked IE8 on another machine and that has it ticked by default.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem for years and finally fixed it:

In the browser window go to Tools > Internet Options > Connections tab > LAN settings. Untick the *Automatically detect settings* box.

Comment: How is this answer different from the one posted a year earlier?